# Saving credentials in GitHub Desktop

Tags: github-desktop

Once in a while (typically a few days), GitHub Desktop asks me for my credentials when I try to sync some repositories:

[image]

Is any way to save credentials for longer periods than a few days?

I use GitHub Desktop with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.